# Navigation bar goes into confusional state

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7

This bug was firstly found in iOS 7, and it can be reproduced in iOS 8 either.

There is a three view controllers A, B and C. Managed by UINavigationController. And I'd like to hide the navigation bar for controller A, not for others.

Here is the code I've written for controller A.

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];

    self.navigationController.navigationBarHidden = YES;
}

- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];

    self.navigationController.navigationBarHidden = NO;
}
```

When user comes back via navigation backBarButtonItem, it works fine for me. But when user slides `backwards` and `forward` from the left side(That is do not actually go backwards to controller A from controller B, but stay in controller B at last), the navigation bar will go into confusional sate.

Here is a demo to show this issue: [Demo]:https://github.com/heistings/NavigationTest

This problem can be simply fixed by disable the interactivePopGestureRecognizer of navigation controller, but can't say it's perfect:

```
self.navigationController.interactivePopGestureRecognizer.enabled = NO;
```

Comment: Yes you are right, it seems to be bug from iOS only.

Comment: @iphonic do not know its a bug or not but using animated property you can achieve this.

Comment: That actually is not a bug. As you have already said, `navigationBar` is really confused, because of changes made on iOS7. Beginning from iOS7, `viewWillAppear:` method doesn't really mean that view will appear, it means, view MAY appear or not. Same for the `viewWillDisappear` method. So, it would be appropriate to do the tasks for appeared view on `viewDidAppear:` method. And, there is a way to identify if view will really appear on `viewWillAppear:` method, can't find it now, but you can search around for that.

Comment: @ChintaN-Maddy-Ramani Using `[self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:NO];` still brings this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may be the best way for this issue since we have got the `animated` from framework:

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];

    [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:animated];
}

- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];

    [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:NO animated:animated];
}
```

Answer (score 3):

use `animated` property to `YES`.

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:YES];
}

- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];
    [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:NO animated:YES];
}
```

Maybe this will help you.

Comment: This is the best way I think, thanks a lot. And this is indeed a navigation bug since using `use animated property to NO` brings this bug too.

Comment: Oh, I found my answer has animation problems, it seems weird when sliding. Yours are best!

Comment: I changed my answer, and It may be perfect

Answer (score 0):

I got your problem.
First Embed navigation controller to ViewController...

1. Click on storyboard...
2. Click on View Controller...
3. Goto Editor section.
4. Click on Embed in and then click on navigation controller.

And then Write the code below:

```
 - (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
   [super viewWillAppear:animated];

   [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:animated];
}

- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];

    [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:NO animated:animated];
    }
```